# Oracle SQL substr function i

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle sql.  I am trying to find the t2.WORK_PHONE after removing any special characters.  Then I want to perform the substr function on it so that it only gets the first 10 numbers starting at the 1st position.  The below works correctly, but how would I apply the substr function to it?

```
, PHONE_NUMBER = 
    NVL((SELECT regexp_replace(t2.WORK_PHONE, '[^0-9]*', '') phone_number
    FROM PS_EMPLOYEES t2
    WHERE t2.EMPLID = PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL_T.EMPLID
), ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the result of `NVL` to the `SUBSTR` function, along with the index and length parameters, like so:

```
, PHONE_NUMBER = SUBSTR
(
 NVL((SELECT regexp_replace(t2.WORK_PHONE, '[^0-9]*', '') phone_number
 FROM PS_EMPLOYEES t2
 WHERE t2.EMPLID = PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL_T.EMPLID), ' ')
 ,1
 ,10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work for you: (Provided all strings would be atleast 10 characters long)

```
SELECT  
SUBSTR
(
    NVL  -- If value returned is null, then replace with 0
    (
       (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(t2.WORK_PHONE, '[^0-9]*', '')  FROM REST_OF_QUERY),
       '0'
    ),
    1, -- From 1st character
    10 -- Till 10th Character
) AS PHONE_NUMBER FROM DUAL;
```

- Consider taking the last 10 values as the phone number, because users may include country code while keying in the phone number.
  For example, if mobile number is 0000000000 and if country code is 99, then your trimmed mobile number would be 9900000000 which is actually wrong. If you have handled it in your design, then ignore this.

To take the last 10 digits where you are not sure of the string length, you can use:

```
SELECT
       SUBSTR(
            PHONE_NUMBER , GREATEST (-10, -length(TO_CHAR(PHONE_NUMBER ))),10) FROM MY_TABLE;
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/972ce/4)**